# ssh authorization only via public key without root access

Tags: ssh

I'm using my friend's VPS (I don't have root access) and I would like to disable SSH password authorization (only public key authorisation). Hovewer as I said ealier I don't have root access and every tutorial I found in the internet require editing global sshd file (which I can't edit).

Comment: I don't think you can make this setup work without root access. You could ask your friend to disable your password: you'll still be able to login using ssh keys, but obviously not with password anymore. As long as you don't need your password on that VPS for other reasons (e.g. sudo), this should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

You must ask your friend to do this. You cannot do it without either root access or using a remote maintenance tool such as [Webmin](http://www.webmin.com/) - which he would also have to install & configure before giving you access.